# Conditional if statement function best method?

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime, if-statement

I am thinking of what the best method would be in this scenario. 
I am trying to look at 4 columns all being timestamps.

```
Col_A        Col_B        Col_A1       Col_B1
Timestamp    Timestamp    Timestamp    Timestamp
```

I am looking for the best way in which I can create an if statement within a function that looks for the earlier time between `Col_A` and `Col_B` and then whichever `col` is earlier I want to find the earlier value within `Col_A1` and `Col_B1`.

for example if the timestamp in `Col_A` is earlier than the timestamp in `Col_B` I want to see if the timestamp for `Col_A1` is earlier than `Col_B1` then I want a new column that says 1.

Basically I am trying to see if the earlier timestamp in the first two columns corresponding timestamp in the last two columns is earlier or later.

so something like if A < B and A_1 < B_1 then 1 and if A < B but A_1>B_1 then 2. So whatever the earlier timestamp is in the first two columns - I want to see if that col timestamp was earlier in the second two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with chaining conditions with `&` for bitwise and:

```
m1 = df['Col_A'] < df['Col_B']
m2 = df['Col_A1'] < df['Col_B1']
m3 = df['Col_A1'] > df['Col_B1']

df['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & m3], [1,2], default=0)
```

If not equal dates:

```
m1 = df['Col_A'] < df['Col_B']
m2 = df['Col_A1'] < df['Col_B1']

#~m2 is like df['Col_A1'] >= df['Col_B1']
df['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2], [1,2], default=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! what do you mean by if not equal dates?

Comment: Then use `!=` instead `>` :)